# How to find out if only one item exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, pug

I have a gallery and when there is only one item in the gallery I want to disable the thumbnails.

I am using a JADE loop to create the thumbnail tray like this:

```
   .thumbnails.tumbnail-tray
      each thumbnail in product.thumbnails
        - var className = (thumbnail.selected) ? 'active' : ''
        .thumb(class=className)
          img(src="images/#{thumbnail.thumb}" main-image="images/#{thumbnail.src}" alt="thumbnail.alt")
```

and this is the JSON structure:

```
"thumbnails": [
    {
      "selected": true,
      "src": "image1.jpg",
      "thumb": "image1_thumb.jpg",
      "alt": ""
    }
  ]
```

What I would like to do is create an if `thumbnails.length => 2` display thumbnails tray `else` don't.

Any ideas how I might be able to do this?

Comment: the comparison operator for __greater than or equal to__ is `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your JSON array to a variable and then use the `length` property:

```
var thumbnails = [
  {
    "selected": true,
    "src": "image1.jpg",
    "thumb": "image1_thumb.jpg",
    "alt": ""
  }
]

if (thumbnails.length > 1) {
  // do something
}
```